# How to create nodes with multiple labels into neo4j with c#

Tags: c#, graph, neo4j

I'm new to neo4j and would like to try to create a setup in c#.
I've been trying to create a node with multiple labels who I'll be able to connect later on.

I've tried different approaches, but it all failed to work.

```
var newUser = new CreateNode { Id = 2, Name = "Test" };
var test1 = new Movie { Title = "The Matrix" };
client.Cypher
    .Create("(user:CreateNode {newUser})")
    .WithParam("newUser", newUser)
    .ExecuteWithoutResults();

public class CreateNode
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("movie")]
    public Movie Movie { get; set; }
}
```

This works for a node with one label, but if I try to add a Movie label to the node I can't seem to find the fix.

If I got it right the label is there so I could create specific RL between nodes. if the user with label young exists, connect with node movie with label animation for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a node with multiple labels, just separate the labels you want with more colons. For example:

```
client.Cypher
    .Create("(user:User:Young:Student {newUser})")
    .WithParam("newUser", newUser)
    .ExecuteWithoutResults();
```